# Show scatter plot and 2D histogram same figure

Tags: seaborn, data-visualization

I have the following scatter plot created with [seaborn.scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

[image]

where I used the code:

```
seaborn.scatterplot(x=X1, y=Y2, s=5, color=".15")
```

Now I want to add a 2D histogram generated from related data but described by the same reference frame. The histogram looks like the following when calculated independently:

[image]

where I have used:

```
seaborn.jointplot(x=X2, y=Y2,kind="hex",marginal_kws=dict(bins=100))
```

So, how can I merge both plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sns.jointplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) returns a [`JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html#seaborn.JointGrid) which has attributes `ax_joint`, `ax_marg_x`, and `ax_marg_y` which can be used to modify the plot.

[`sns.scatterplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) can accept an `ax` as a parameter on which to draw the scatter plot.

A combined operation could look like:

```py
import seaborn as sns

# ... read in or generate data
g = sns.jointplot(x=X2, y=Y2, kind="hex", marginal_kws=dict(bins=100))
sns.scatterplot(x=X1, y=Y2, s=5, color=".15", ax=g.ax_joint)
```